# table2CSV Skip first row

Tags: php, jquery, csv, export-to-csv

I'm using option 3.1 from this plugin http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php
How could I skip the first row? Could it be done to the $_REQUEST['csv_text']

```
<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" > 
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
<input type="submit" value="Get CSV File" onclick="getCSVData()">
</form>

<script>
function getCSVData(){
 var csv_value=$('#example1').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
 $("#csv_text").val(csv_value); 
}
</script>

<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my-data.csv\"");
$data=stripcslashes($_REQUEST['csv_text']);
echo $data; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:
     $_REQUEST['csv_text'] = preg_replace('/^[^\n]*\n/','', $_REQUEST['csv_text']);